# Incorrect calculation of powers - C

Tags: c, formula

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
#define M_E 2.71828

double a, b, c;
double d;

void main() 
{
  scanf("%lf", &a);
  scanf("%lf", &b);
  for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
  {
    c = a * pow(M_E,(1/(double)i+1)) + (1/b);
    printf("%lf\n", c);
  }  
}
```

I am getting incorrect values for the variable c, not sure why. Tried working around bracketing and tried to avoid `pow()` function, no clue what else to try.

--> I need my code to reflect the following formula:

```
a * e^(1/(i+1)) + (1/b)
```

[From comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684071/incorrect-calculation-of-powers-c/53684269#comment94225045_53684121) If I input a value for a as 2 and for b as 2 - I should be getting 3.79744... but I am getting 6.074.

Comment: `void main()` is an illegal signature for a hosted environment. The minimum is `int main(void)` (and don't use empty parentneses if a function does not take parameters)

Comment: You only show the final value of `c`, what is the loop for? What are you trying to compute, and is `(double)i+1` an error?

Comment: Not sure if this is an error, but `(1/(double)i+1)` is the same as `(1+1/(double)i)`

Comment: `#include <math.h> // I know its unnecessary `  What?!?!?  That's wrong.  `#include <math.h>` is necessary, per [**7.12.7.4 The pow functions**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.7.4).

Comment: `math.h` will give you a better value for *e* too.

Comment: Tip: When debugging floating point issues, report `double` values with `"%e"` or `"%g"`.  It is more informative with large and small values than `"%f"`,

Comment: @WeatherVane I put the print outside of the loop just so it's easier to troubleshoot, cause I only get one value for output. (double)i+1 is not showing up as an error

Comment: SIddharth M., "I am getting incorrect values for the variable c" lacks information.  Post input used, output seen and output expected.

Comment: I don't mean C error; I mean formula translation (from math equation on paper to C) error. I thought it would be unusual to have `1/42+1` rather than `1+1/42` or `1/(42+1)`

Comment: I said so 16 minutes before the edit!! Hooray pmg! :)

Comment: @pmg You have earned the [seer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle) badge - but then, you should not be surprised.;-)

Comment: Note: instead of `pow(M_E, y)`, just use `exp(y)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Wrong coding of formula**

To reflect the following formula : a * e^(1/(i+1)) + (1/b).`

Add 1 then divide.

```
//                     v------------v 
// c = a * pow(M_E,(   1/ (double)i+1   )) + (1/b);
c    = a * pow(M_E,(   1/((double)i+1)  )) + (1/b);
```

Output meets OP goal [I should be getting 3.79744...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684071/incorrect-calculation-of-powers-c/53684269#comment94225045_53684121) .

```
3.797441
```

---

With a more accurate `e`, code can get a more accurate result.

```
#define M_E 2.7182818284590452353602874713527
// output
3.797443
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is giving the expected result. You are probably expecting the wrong values. I have re-arranged the brackets in your expression for `c`, to show what's actually happening.

You should also replace your `pow` with the `exp` function, since you are essentially taking an exponential. See how the new variable `d` is calculated in the code below.

I also moved `printf` statement inside the loop to output all the values. The `<math.h>` header is definitely required, and you do not need to redefine `M_E`, it's already defined in the header with much higher accuracy than you have.

**I have edited the code to meet the new requirements of `c = a * e^(1/(i+1)) + (1/b)`.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> // This is necessary!!

double a, b, c;

double d;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
scanf("%lf", &a);
scanf("%lf", &b);
for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
{
  c = a * pow(M_E, 1/(double)(i + 1)) + (1/b);
  d = a * exp(1/(double)(i+1)) + (1/b); //this is equal to c!
  printf("%e\n", c); //use %e to print doubles
}  
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yes I see what you have done. I need my code to reflect the following formula : a * e^(1/(i+1)) + (1/b).

Comment: @SIddharthM. please put that essential information *in the question*.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in

```
1/(double)i+1
```

which should be

```
1/((double)i+1)
```

or even

```
1.0 / (i + 1)
```